# What is the symbol for this very site? What type of diode?

Tags: diodes, symbol

What specific type of diode (presumably) is the logo for Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange?

Comment: Nothing really as far as I can tell.

Comment: That's a 1N4148. Or maybe a '914.  Hard to tell exactly!

Comment: With the circle round it, I think it's old enough to be an OA45.

Comment: I suspect it is a relic from vacuum tube days (5U4GB, for example.) When semiconductors appeared on the scene, the cathode and anode needed to be replaced with something distinctive, while keeping the basic diode/triode/etc symbol recognizable to those more familiar with tubes. But I'm no historian. I hear Don Lancaster is still alive (Spehro?) He'd know.

Comment: a diode in space

Comment: @jonk, I looked up Don Lancaster's site here: https://www.tinaja.com/whtnu20.shtml. Since he posted on may 26, proof of life as it were. Even if the site design made my eyes bleed, even by Web 1.0 standards.

Comment: @hacktastical Yeah. It's definitely done the same way I'd do it -- with DOS edit on MS-DOS 5.0 running on a 33 MHz 80386 box with 12 16-bit ISA slots and 4 8-bit ISA, an IBM VGA card (or, perhaps, my EGA card if I'm feeling "retro" -- recalling those days writing graphics software for it.) I still remember when uunet finally made it possible for the hoi polloi to get email access to the internet. (Way before HTML.) Wonderful thing about the mid-90's is that there were no people sanitizing the web and you could find real people writing real reviews of real products. Those are on page 9000, now.

Comment: @hacktastical Woah, he's just recently updated that to a "new" cleaner look for mobile compatibility.

Comment: That diode looks like it looks like it would have a PCB designator "CR" instead of "D".

Comment: OSD. Ordinary Silicon Diode.

Comment: How come this isn't moved to meta yet.. come on.

Comment: @Spehro Nah, think it's just been updated for Netscape 6.0...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Well, I hope I'm doing as well at his age (he has to be 80+/-  years old by now).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yeah, Don Lancaster is an amazing guy.  His book "Incredible Secret Money Machine" shaped my life...

Comment: More of a meta post than anything, but it is *"[web-designer friendly](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5410/design-update-is-now-live)"* diode that I am grateful is actually a schematic symbol instead of an artist's rendition of a schematic symbol.

Answer (score 21):

"Standard" diode.

Not LED, not schottky, not zener, not TVS...

The circle is an optional style that was popular a while back, but now diodes are mostly drawn without the circle around them.

Comment: I've seen some styles that call for the circle to indicate a "real" device where the uncircled version is an ideal device.

Comment: @ThePhoton That's interesting!  Do you have a link you can share?

Comment: is the unfilled triangle significant?

Comment: In a rather informal convention, a circle around the element means a discrete element, no circle means it is a part of an integrated circuit. Transistors are for sure drawn like this and the circle means packaging. One can see a Darlington transistor to be drawn with a circle around both transistors.

Comment: Many years ago, the circle *was* used to denote a discrete device. Symbols without them were part of an integrated circuit so when looking at the circuit of a TTL part (to understand how it operated, which is still a good idea) there were no circles. This was almost universal in the 70s and early 80s but slowly fell out of use when ICs started to simply show an *equivalent* circuit in the datasheets (and designers couldn't be bothered to draw a circle that started to have no real meaning).

Comment: Also, I think some 1980s schematics (japanese?) did use circles around diodes to indicate LEDs as opposed to other diodes....